# Помогите сделать перенаправление всех страниц сайта на урл со слэшем на вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Добрый день проженым программерам! Очень часто я сталкиваюсь с перенаправлениями в htaccess, но как правило они стандартные и окей гугл и все ок.
А сейчас патовая ситуация: логики записи регулярных выражений я до конца не понимаю. Есть сайт на вордпресс, там уже прописаны перенаправления на урл без www и на https. Мне же необходимо сделать редирект всех страниц на урл со слэшем на конце + редирект с множественным слэшем на конце на один + в том числе множественные слэши после доменного имени. И я потерялась уже в первой задаче: нашла много вариантов кода, но не один не срабатывает. Вот мой файл htaccess, где последние 4 строчки должны перенаправлять все страницы на урл со слэшем. Пожалуйста подскажите, что не так и как с этим справиться:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?hadassah.moscow [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yandex.ru [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC,F,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hadassah\.moscow$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hadassah.moscow/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4):

> Пожалуйста подскажите, что не так и как с этим справиться

Нужно очистить хтацесс от мусора, а в ВП задать нужный формат пермалинков (с последним слешем в данном случае)

Comment: А что из этого мусор, кроме последних четырех строчек?

Comment: Мне нужно не просто чтобы ссылки формировались со слэшем на конце, а чтобы старые проиндексированные без слэша перенаправлялись на страницы со слэшем

Comment: @АлёнаЧащина. Мусор - всё, что не сгенерировано ВП. Редирект и будет.

Comment: @АлёнаЧащина, вам  еще и сервер надо нормально настроить - по http открывается другой сайт (аппачевская заглушка.)